# Ubuntu 16.10 won't shutdown

Tags: shutdown, reboot

Ubuntu won't shutdown, reboot, suspend or even let me log in as guest. When shutting down / rebooting it hangs at `Reached System Shutdown`, when suspended the screen goes black but the computer is still on and I have to forcibly shut it down, when logging in as guest it takes me back to my account login.

I am running it on an Asus N552VW laptop, Ubuntu is installed on the SSD. This computer has the known problem of not booting up the installer for Ubuntu unless using nomodeset, so I did that and then, once installed, I just deleted it from grub since it set the resolution to 800x600 (my monitor is 4K!). I later wanted to install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers, but they caused the PC to go into a login loop so I removed them and I am currently using Nouveau. Now I can't shut my PC down (with nomodeset it worked).

Things I already tried:

- alternative commands to shutdown (shutdown -h, halt, from GUI...);
- `swapoff -a` before shutting down;
- `acpi=force in /etc/default/grub`, both in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` (even both at the same time);
- `acpi=Force` AND `apm= power_off` AND adding apm module;
- deleting `quiet splash` from grub;
- blacklisting `dw_dmac` and `dw_dmac_core`;
- reinstalling Ubuntu.

None of the above worked. To shut down I currently do it from GUI and when it says `reached target shutdown` I just hold down the power button.

Additional information:

- Ubuntu is installed on dual boot alongside Windows 10;
- Windows fast boot is disabled;
- Ubuntu is version 16.10 64 bit on kernel 8.4;

Does anyone have a solution? Even a workaround would be enough.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, looks like I solved it.

As I thought, the problem was caused by drivers: I managed to install the NVIDIA drivers from terminal using`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and now everything works properly!

Comment: You've earned my upvote. Drivers are (almost :P) always the best solution.